# XSL short `value-of` with `disable-output-escaping`?

Tags: python, xslt, lxml, libxslt

I'm processing the following (example) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>&amp; &amp; &amp;</root>
```

through the following (example) XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:output
    method="html"
    version="4.0"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <input value="{/root}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using Python and `lxml` (`libxslt-1.1.17`), and I'm getting the following output:

```
<input value="&amp;amp; &amp;amp; &amp;amp;" />
```

I understand that I can get around this with the following template:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <input>
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="/root" 
          disable-output-escaping="yes" 
          />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </input>
  </xsl:template>
```

but that's a **lot** of typing. Having worked with XSL within PHP I don't remember ever having to use this work-around for unquoting XML entities using the short-form `value-of`. Is there a short fix for this, so we don't have to keep typing the whole of the above?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure your posted example input and stylesheet are complete and actually demonstrate the problem (at least the stylesheet is missing the `xsl` namespace declaration)? Session transcript available here: http://pastebin.com/rbMhBXRm

Comment: Your input source has three `&` ampersand character, that they happen to be encode as character entities (as it should be). There is no way this would be output as an "HTML encode" like `&amp;amp;` unless they were not character entities in the first place but five characters `&amp;` like in a CDATA section.

Answer (score 1):

DOE in fact **is designed** for such cases. Sorry, if you know that, just to be consecutive.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping

> Normally, the xml output method escapes & and < (and possibly other characters) when outputting text nodes. This ensures that the output is well-formed XML. However, it is sometimes convenient to be able to produce output that is almost, but not quite well-formed XML; for example, the output may include ill-formed sections which are intended to be transformed into well-formed XML by a subsequent non-XML aware process. For this reason, XSLT provides a mechanism for disabling output escaping. An xsl:value-of or xsl:text element may have a disable-output-escaping attribute...

I guess the real pain is that you **can't** use DOE in atrribute value's expression, e.g. `{disable-output-escaping(root)}`.

So, I can't think of any way to shorten this.

Comment: Read closer the question. Can you reproduce the problem? I think you can't.

Comment: @Alejandro. Oops. I answered mainly the "Is there a short fix for this, so we don't have to keep typing the whole of the above?" part. You can downvote.